# JQuery: looping over multidimensional array of form input elements

Tags: jquery, forms, multidimensional-array

With php I generate a form based on a multidimensional array. The form contains a number of input type="text" fieldpairs that are named "items[level1][level2][price]" and "items[level1][level2][amount]". I display these in a table.

Now, I want to add two things using jquery:

1. an extra column that displays the total price for this item (=items[level1][level2][price].value * items[level1][level2][amount].value)
2. At the bottom row: the total price for all items.

These values should update on every change-event of one of the mentioned textinputs.

I've been hitting a wall the last few hours, I hope someone here could give me some pointers.

Here's a snippet of the generated html:

```
<form name="formname">
<table name="tablename">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[1][2][amount]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[1][2][price]" /></td>
        <td>Here I want to display amount*price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[1][8][amount]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[1][8][price]" /></td>
        <td>Here I want to display amount*price</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[3][4][amount]" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="classname" name="items[3][4][price]" /></td>
        <td>Here I want to display amount*price</td>
    </tr>
    ...more rows like above...
    <tr>Some more formelements that have nothing to do with the problem</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Here I want to display the sum of all amount*price</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do it.  The basic idea is when the `.classname` input changes, look for the parent row and then use that to look for the inputs in that row to multiply together and the `td` to put the value it.  You can look for them using a "name contains" `[attr*=string]` selector:

```
$('.classname').on('change', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = row.find('[name*=amount]').val() * row.find('[name*=price]').val();

    row.find('td:last').text(total);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/DJtTs/

Or if they are always the 1st/2nd column, use `.eq()` or `:eq()`:

```
$('.classname').on('change', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = row.find('input:eq(0)').val() * row.find('input:eq(1)').val();

    row.find('td:last').text(total);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/DJtTs/1/

EDIT MARCO:

```
$(".classname").live('change', function(e) {
    //replaced on with live so the function will stick.
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var total = row.find('[name*=amount]').val() * row.find('[name*=price]').val();
    row.find('[id="totalitemprice"]').text("\u20ac "+total.toFixed(2));
    //added eurosign and rounded to 2 decimals

    //Start computing total value
    var totaltotal = parseFloat(0);
    $.each($('[id="totalitemprice"]'), function(key, value) {
        //Loop across all totalitemprices
        totaltotal += parseFloat(value.firstChild.data.replace(/\u20ac /g,''));
        //Find out what's in the cell, strip the eurosign, parse it to Float and add it to the total
    });

    $("#totalprice").text("\u20ac "+totaltotal.toFixed(2));
    //Finally, write the total price to the approprioate cell.
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff! This gives me a push in the right direction, probably enough :)

Comment: Great!  When you use someone's answer it is polite to upvote and/or accept the answer (click the checkmark below the number next to the question).  You probably can't upvote when you are a new user, but you can always accept answers to questions you ask.

Comment: I got that Jeff, but I wanted to wait until I was 100% sure it would solve my problem. I accepted the answer and added my final jquery code to it. Thanks as well for the jsFiddle link - I did not know that and it rocks!

Comment: @Marco, glad it helped.  As a note, `on()` replaces `live()` in newer versions of jQuery.  To make `on()` "stick", as you say, you need to call it on any parent element, and filter it with the classname:  `$('tr').on('click', '.classname', function() {...`.   This will do the same as your `live` call.